# android- in app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am looking to develop an application where the price of an
application varies.
For instance, the application costs $10 for 6 months, $20 from 6
months to 1 year, and $30 after 1 year.
1. is it possible for me to control the pricing using 'in-app
billing' ?
2. once i publish the app, is it possible to change the price?

Help appreciated.

Thanks,
Mith

Answer (score 0):

Using Android in-app billing you can set-up "products" within the Market Developer Console with different prices.

In your example you could set-up 3 products for the different subscription lengths and in your app code handle these being purchased and record in a db/shared preferences an expiry date for when the app should go back to basic use.

Since the products are managed on the Market Developer Console you can vary the pricing at will and when the users subscription expires they will renew at the latest pricing you have set.